# Unable to complete Customize support processes challenge in lightning super badge

Tags: apex, soql, community, salesforce1-app, trailhead

Hi Friends i am working on Lightning super badge challenge.I stuck in challenge 7 because

The requirement is

In addition to sales, you need to automate service. Remove all existing Case Reason values, except for Feedback and Other. Then add the following new values: Injury, Equipment Related, SOS, Fulfillment Issue, Open Adventure Package Issue, Closed Adventure Package Issue, Scheduling, Cancellation/Refund, and Special Needs.

**Expedition Leader Support**

Create a way for expedition leaders to log cases from their phones and name it **New Expedition Leader Case**.

Ensure the ability to create a new case is available from Lightning Experience, and for data integrity reasons, the new case should be created directly from the fulfillment record. This short form creates a case related for the fulfillment and includes the subject, description, reason, status, priority, and related explorer. The explorer and fulfillment information should be auto-populated with the related data from the fulfillment and have a default priority of High.

So i create a process process and add fulfillment as object.In immediate actions i create an action to create case with values explorer reference everything.

But i missed something requirements understanding. Can you please with this to achieve

Comment: Perhaps you missed this part of the requirement: `the new case should be created directly from the fulfillment record`? There's been some discussion in SF Meta, that SuperBadge Questions perhaps shouldn't be answered here. It's a bit like answering a Certification Question. I suggest you go back through everything and re-read the problem carefully, take a break and read it again. The badges aren't meant to be easy.

Comment: OK i will work on it and let you know.@crmprogdev